# How to convert DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS (24 hours format) to DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS (24 hours format) in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

How to convert DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS (24 hours format) to DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS (24 hours format). Eg below:

```
Given input: 11-10-2017 11:23:30
Required output: 11-Oct-2017 11:23:30
```

Comment: I am not getting any difference according to your question in the given input and required output so can you please confirm it.

Comment: Given input includes Month no. in number while in the required output is the month name (first 3 character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Datetime DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, '11-10-2017 11:23:30', 105)

SELECT 
    [Full] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DateTime, 113),
    Truncated = SUBSTRING(
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @DateTime, 113),
        1,
        20)

-- Full: 11 Oct 2017 11:23:30:000
-- Truncated: 11 Oct 2017 11:23:30
```